# Time completion in working hours

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

Okay, not so much a programming problem, but I can only seem to think of really complicated methods to solve this.

There is a script we run in the office. We need to determine how long this script takes only in working hours (working hours being 9am - 5pm). For example, let's say the script is started on Monday at 2pm, and finishes on Tuesday at 4pm. This script has taken 26 hours to complete, but only 10 hours to complete. This script can finish in a single working day, but can also span over many days. The script can only start and end in a working day. The timestamping is done with Unix format.

I do not have a clue how this could be done in SQL, but I know the network admin would prefer this.

The server-side scripting language is PHP. So this would be the second option available. My attempt is below:

```
$workingDay = 24;
$workingDayHours = 8;
$workingTime = 0;

while($timeTaken >= $workingDay) {
  $workingTime += $workingDayHours;
  $timeTaken -= $workingDay;
}
$workingTime += $timeTaken;
```

I can't really think properly right now, too much work on, so although this method is dumb, it seems to work in this scenario since the $timeTaken will always be <= 8 || >= 24.

Anyways, would be great to see a better and smarter method (perhaps one that would work with any number of hours). SQL would be great to see too.

Comment: What happens to the script if it doesn't finish before 5 pm on a work day?  Is it paused and resumed at 9 am the next day?  Or does it continue - in which case what happens if it ends at 9 pm?

Comment: How about weekends? Starting a script at Fri, 4pm, running on Sat and Sun, ending on Mon, 9am counts as 2 hours?

Comment: @aleks-g Well, I have no idea how the system was put together, but apparently the time stamp can only be within 9am and 5pm. The script will not finish outside these times.

Comment: God damn new *press enter to post comment*, so annoying...

Comment: @arnep Hm, weekends is something I didn't think about. The script should count as 1 hour if it started at 4pm and finished at 9am. The script I posted however, will not work like that :P

Comment: Of course then there's holidays too, and this system has no way of communicating with the outside world so somebody would have to manage a calendar just for some times...

Answer (score 0):

something like this (will only work if the job starts and completes between 9:00-17:00)...
(not tested sorry)

The elapsed duration in hours:

```
 HOUR(TIMEDIFF(enddatetime-startdatetime))
```

To calculate the number of working hours:

We need to remove the n 16 hour periods that the job was not running,
(any job running for more than 16 hours must be running over n days)

```
duration - (FLOOR(duration/16)*16)
```

to get:

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(enddatetime-startdatetime)) - 
          (FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(enddatetime-startdatetime))/16)*16) AS duration
```

If you want to remove weekends you could simply look at the start and end week number, if they are not the same remove 48 hours (for each weekend the job runs over), then remove this value from the above duration

```
(week(enddatetime,1) - week(startdatetime,1)) * 48
```

Comment: this returns 3 for 7pm-20pm run, which should be 0.

Comment: furthermore, if the run is 4pm till 7am next morning, your formula returns 0 (15-15), when it should be 1.

Comment: you are quite correct, it will only work if the job starts and ends during working hours (9-5), but see Mr Carls comments : 'apparently the time stamp can only be within 9am and 5pm. The script will not finish outside these times'